# Will we obtain an infinitesimal when we neglect $x^2$ in $x+x^2$, as ${x \to 0}$?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

Let's assume that we have $2xdx + dx^2$. We can neglect $dx^2$ and we'll obtain $2xdx$.
Let's assume that we have $x+x^2$ and ${x \to 0}$. We can also neglect $x^2$, but will we obtain an infinitesimal $x$ as such as $dx$?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you'll just get $0$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah When $dx$ goes to zero we get $2xdx$ and $dx$ is infinitesimal. I mean that we get $x$ from $x+x^2$ when $x$ goes to zero in a similar way.